# React-router-dom redirect not working in any way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I have tried different ways to make redirect.The page is still on same route. Nothing worked for me though the same code worked on previous projects. Using react-router-dom v5.2.0

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from 'root/pages/Login';
import Page404 from 'root/pages/404'; 

interface RouterProps {
  title: string;
}

const LOGIN = 'login';
const PRODUCTS = 'products';

class Admin extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<RouterProps>> {

  componentDidMount(): void {
    this.props.history.push('/');
    window.open('/')
  }
  switchRoutes(): JSX.Element {
    const { title } = this.props.match.params;
    switch(title) {
      case LOGIN:
        return <Login />
      case PRODUCTS:
        return <h1>Products</h1>
      default:
        return <Redirect to="/404" />
        //return <Page404 />
    }
  }

  render(): JSX.Element {
    return this.switchRoutes();
  }
}

export default withRouter(Admin);
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? What is being rendered if not a redirect?

Comment: Which route does it end up on, `/404`?

Comment: No errors. I tried different routes actually, none works

Comment: Are you confident that the `Admin` component is even being rendered? How does this component get rendered?

Comment: It's being rendered in router. /login and /products work well

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in "react-static-router" (we are using SSR) so it is a configuration problem.